# Identify roles from Azure ACS

Tags: c#, azure, identity, claims-based-identity, acs

As we knew in Web got a lot of tutorial for Azure ACS, but most of it stop at inset simple ACS into website or application. Now, i wondering is that possible to identify and link up all the famous user oauth provider, and add them a new user in database then assign role to them ? After the process, they just simply click any provider then will bring them back to the same  account ? Do you having such tutorial can share? Here is the process flow i want to make:
Window live + google + Yahoo + Facebook, one person may having all four account, but then i need their info also, then i create my cuatom data entering page and the problem is how can i link up ? How can  withdraw the unique id to identify ?  So i can recognize it..and assign role to it..

Question 1: how to link up ?

Question 2: how to identify in system?

Question 3: how to give role ? Not giving from azure admin page but through the code

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one thing you should be aware of, when working with ACS (and with Claims in general) - you shall get to know the [Claims](http://blogs.staykov.net/2012/05/introduction-to-claims.html).

Now, to the ACS specific question. Windows Azure Access Control service is not the magic wand that will do what you desire automatically. ACS is the easiest way to get working with Claims, and to work with only one set of specific claims, and don't bother with all different implementations of different protocols. In fact, what you work with, when creating browser based application, is [WS-Federation protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Federation) (and [SAML token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) by default, but you can also use SWT token), and not OAuth protocol. The user uniqueness you get, when someone logs-in with your site, when using ACS is the strict combination of following two factors:

- User identity
- [ACS namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185908.aspx)

The uniqueness you get is [NameIdentifier claim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes.nameidentifier.aspx) (represented by: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier).

The first catch is that, say I am "john.doe@gmail.com" identified to your site through http://yourcompany.accesscontrol.windows.net you will get nameidentifier "X". When, I, the same "john.doe@gmail.com" identify myself to your site, through http://yourcompany-live.accesscontrol.windows.net/, you get nameidentifier "Y"! And this is true for all identity providers, which you link via your Access Control Service.

The second catch is: Live ID identity provider, when configured via ACS, will only give you a NameIdentifier claim. And nothing more.

Now to the questions:

> Question 1: how to link up ?

The only feasible way to link up identities, is to built your own linking logic in your application. What I would do, is to stop using all the auto generated code and passive redirection to ACS, but to handle some of the Passive Federation manually. This would mean - I will watch out whether the user is logged-in or no. If not logged in, I will redirect the user to my own custom login page, where I will get from ACS the configured login options. When the user is logged-in, I will create an entry in my own user data base for that user. I will have fields (or linked table) for all possible identity providers that I would like to link up to a single user. Understand, I will store all the NameIdentifiers the user may have. Now, how will I link a user account. There may be different approaches. First, you must indentify the user to allow him/her to link an account. Then create let's say a "linkage ticket" with some unique ID (not GUID, to be easily remembered by the user). Show this ID to the user, and offer him an option to login with another provider (retrieve the list of privers from ACS). When user comes with another provider - show the field when one could enter the ticket. Check the ticket, and if it is valid - link to the existing account.

> Question 2: how to identify in system?

As mentioned in answe one - you will need to have your own custom user database, where you will have one account per user, but that account will hold all the NameIdentifier claims, issued by the different authorities. Thus you will be able to uniquely identify the users with linked accoutns.

> Question 3: how to give role ? Not giving from azure admin page but
>   through the code

In your architecture it will be very hard to maintain the roles in the ACS, because of the complexity you enter when requiring to link multiple accounts. I suggest that you keep user-role assignment withing the application database. The part that you have local user accounts, you will assign role(s) to each account.

Note, when I say local user account, I don't mean to support local login credentials, but just user profiles!

Comment: it's detailed and great answer ! Thx =D